# Mobile Safari clears cookies and LocalStorage on hard-reset

Tags: ios, cookies, browser, mobile-safari, storage

I'm currently hard at work developing my first Web application, and I have stumbled hard upon an issue on the iOS mobile-devices' Safari Browser.

If I create a cookie set to expire in `x` days (basically any cookie created, session-only or otherwise), and hard-reset the browser on the phone (as in closing the app entirely or restarting the phone), the cookie is destroyed.

Why is that? And how can I avoid it?

The same thing happens with objects stored in LocalStorage.

Also, if it can not be avoided, what other way of storing my app-data should I use? Server-side storage is last resort here.

The phone settings have been checked, nothing indicates that the browser is rejecting- or is set to clear cookies on session/app exit.

Comment: You can't rely on user's phone cookies / local storage to store important states; use server-side storage instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shivan Raptor said, important data should be stored server-side.

After some fiddling, I also found that localStorage apparently survives app hard-reset, whereas cookies do not.

Closing.